# Multiple Selection in ForEach Extension Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is it possible to select multiple entiies in ForEach Extension Method?

(i.e)

partial code is given

```
DataTableA.AsEnumerable().ToList().
    ForEach(x=>
    {
        x.SetField<string>("Name","Jon Skeet"),
        x.SetField<string>("msg","welcome")
    });
```

when i apply multiple selection in ForEach

```
 x=>
{
    x.SetField<string>("Name","Jon Skeet"),
    x.SetField<string>("msg","welcome")
}
```

I am unable to complete the statement.Help Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the lambda compile to valid C#:

```
DataTableA.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(
     x=>  
     {
         x.SetField<string>("Name","Jon Skeet");
         x.SetField<string>("msg","welcome");
      });
```

That being said, I'd caution against this.  Using ForEach is [purposely causing side-effects](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/), and it's really not more concise than the foreach statement in the language itself.  Personally, I'd just write:

```
foreach(var element in DataTableA.AsEnumerable())
{
    element.SetField<string>("Name","Jon Skeet");
    element.SetField<string>("msg","welcome");
}
```

This, in my opinion, is much more clear than the first statement (and shorter, and more efficient, since it doesn't force a full enumeration into the list, and a second enumeration of the list elements).

Comment: Thanks once again i have updated my code as per your suggestion